# How can I make a tendril flame like aura visual effect?

Tags: shaders, unreal-4, particles, post-processing

I am a bit new to UE4 and I'm trying to get a tendril flame like aura like the picture below.

Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Should I use post processing or particles?

[image]

Comment: Post processing and particle system are two different things. You need particle system to achieve your goal and then you can apply post processing effect to make it look better. Post processing is optional.

Comment: @Saad Anees    How would I go about combining the two to get this effect

Comment: See the tutorials. Im sure you can google it easily

Comment: I recommend downloading the Content Examples. It's from the Unreal.

Comment: The yellow outline looks like fresnel to me.

Comment: I've googled it and there aren't many tutorials on this topic.